# Change fab button arrow color on AppCompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I want to change the color of the arrow in the fab button from black to white, this is how it looks currently in the theme editor:

### [image]

And this is my code in `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="colorForeground">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="navigationBarColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="statusBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I have already manage to change the text color in the App Bar thanks to other answers but I haven't found a way to change this other part.

I'm using `appcompat-v7:25.2.0`

Answer (score 0):

You could specify any icon with any color for your fab, using `src` parameter:

Here is an example from our project:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/training_player"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/play_fap"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        />
```

Or you can simply add color tint to change color of existing icon:

```
android:tint="@color/white"
```

Comment: This would change the color for an specific fab, right? Is there a way to change it as part of the app theme?

Comment: Yes, it is for a single one. I am not sure if you can use something css-like: for all FloatingActionButton use android:tint=white... You definitely can create a style with needed tint for icon and background color (if it is different from accent) in a style and apply this style manually to all buttons.

Comment: I looked at the them more thoroughly and found that you can add style for all buttons (if they don't specify another one) using construction like this in your styles.xml: 
`<style name="ApplicationStyle" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/CKButton</item>
    </style>`. But I don't see fabs there =(

Answer (score 0):

The following solution relies on support vectors. [Read more here.](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88)

#### my_vector_drawable.xml

```
<vector
    android:tint="?colorControlNormal">
    ...
</vector>
```

You can tint support vector drawables. `?colorControlNormal` is an attribute defined by your theme. In light themes its semi-transparent black, in dark themes it's semi-transparent or opaque white.

#### layout.xml

```
<FloatingActionButton
    style="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_vector_drawable/>
```

Two things happen here:

1. Use `app:srcCompat` which will safely set a support vector drawable on all API levels.
2. Set a dark theme on the FAB. This will make the icon and the ripple effect white.

Theme explanation:

- Dark theme = light foregrounds (text, icons, highlights), dark backgrounds.
- Light theme = dark foregrounds, light backgrounds.